# Is there a way to display embedded tweets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've set up a Zapier and IFTTT integration to a Google sheet.  It outputs the tweet contents in separate columns (username, tweet text, embed code).  Is there a way to have the HTML embed code rendered in the cell?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information), and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: I don't think so. You can render html in a sidebar though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but you could use Google Apps Script's HTML Service to create a dialog or sidebar to show that.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs